# How would I obtain the primary key of a newly inserted table row in a SQL Database from Access VBA?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a SQL Server database with a MS Access frontend.

I need to obtain the primary key of a newly inserted row in a SQL Server database table.

I have tried `SCOPE_INDENTITY()` and `@@IDENTITY` without success.

I have this `Department` table consisting of two columns:

1. `ID` - primary key identity column
2. `DeptName` of type `NVARCHAR(255)`

This is an example of the VBA code:

```
Dim idRecordset As Recordset
Dim lastId as Integer

DoCmd.RunSql "INSERT INTO Departments (DeptName) VALUES ('Department A')
Set idRecordset = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT @@IDENTITY")
lastId = idRecordSet.Fields(0).Value

idRecordset.Close
Set idRecordset = Nothing
```

- The `INSERT` statement succeeds. A new row for 'Department A' is added to the `Departments` table
- `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` throws a *no such column* error.
- `SELECT @@IDENTITY` always returns 0.

Questions and notes:

1. Can `SELECT @@IDENTITY` be used from Access VBA?
2. I will try creating a SQL Server stored procedure and see if it can be called from Access VBA

Comment: You need to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` **immediately** after the `INSERT` and within the  same batch; performing the `INSERT` and then using a separate command to get the `IDENTITY` won't work.

Comment: So a SQL stored procedure is the only solution (or can you use multiple commands in an OpenRecordset)?

Comment: My VBA is *very* rusty, but I am confident that you can but `INSERT` and `SELECT` in the same batch in a single command in VBA (I am sure I have, in fact, done it in decades past).

Comment: @HansUp's solution works for me too. I use `db.OpenRecordset("SELECT @@IDENTITY", dbOpenSnapshot)` but I don't see how the recordset type would make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using ADO and directly querying SQL server.

I prefer using the `OUTPUT` clause over `scope_identity()` since it handles nonidentity calculated defaults as well, but both should work fine.

```vb
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open "Some connection string to SQL server"
Set rs = conn.Execute("DECLARE @NewID table(NewId Integer);" & _ 
   "INSERT INTO dbo.Departments (DeptName) " & _ 
   "OUTPUT Inserted.Id INTO @NewID VALUES ('Department A'); " & _ 
   "SELECT * FROM @NewID")
LastId = rs.Fields(0).Value
```

You may prefer to separately execute the query and then opening a recordset using `SELECT scope_identity()`, which saves you from that long SQL clause, but adds an ever-so-slight delay since it adds a trip to the server.